# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function

Tags: jquery

Se foi meio dia e eu não consegui encontrar o problema, de um fato que achava ser simples.
Na documentação do Jquery, consta:
$( "#book" ).animate({

Já tentei colocar um Jquery mais novo, mais antigo, mas, não vai.
Não funciona um script simples de scroll que preciso implementar.

```js
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
  var aTag = $("a[name='" + aid + "']");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: aTag.offsetTop
  }, 'slow');
}

$("#quem-somos").on('click', function() {
  scrollToAnchor('section-quem-somos');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu__item" href="#" id="quem-somos">
  <span class="menu__item-name">Quem somos</span>
</a>
<section class="bloco_historia" id="section-quem-somos">Bloco</section>
```

Ele está próximo do rodapé.
Se eu mudar para o head, não dá erro, mas também não funciona.

Comment: Por que no jQuery você busca pela tag `<a>` que possui o atributo `name` sendo que seu elemento não possui tal atributo? Aliás, nem um elemento `<a>` ele é, é um `<section>` que possui o `id`.

Comment: Entendi. Mas troquei o name para id, mas nada ainda.

Comment: E trocou o `a` para `section`?

Answer (score 0):

Será preciso mudar um pouco do seu código para que funcione. No Javascript sugiro fazer algo deste tipo:

```
function scrollToAnchor(sectionID) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#section-' + sectionID).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
}

$("a.menu__item").on('click', function() {
  var linkID= $(this).attr('id');
  scrollToAnchor(linkID);
});
```

#### Detalhe da mudança:

A `function scrollToAnchor` recebe o ID da `<section>` como parâmetro e no `.animate()` pega o `offset` via selector do elemento que precisa ser exibido por *scroll*.

Repara que o *selector* é a junção do ID do link/menu com o prefixo *section*, logo, `'section-' + sectionID` fica `'section-quem-somos'`.

E no *click*, o *selector* para o evento fica mais genérico, cobrindo apenas os elementos do contexto do menu, proporcionando que você possa incluir novos links. Já o *handle* do evento chama a função `scrollToAnchor()` passando como parâmetro uma string do próprio ID do elemento clicado.